# Not getting "Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat" option

Tags: support, comments, chat

On [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387430/is-there-an-issue-with-the-setcookie-function-in-this-code/55387577?noredirect=1#comment97498603_55387577) I've been having an extended discussion with OP, trying to resolve an issue. Despite 15 comments (just between the two of us) being posted, the offer to move the discussion to chat has not appeared. This isn't the first time this has happened, but it seems to be happening more of late so I thought it was time to raise the question. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only get the chance to move a comment discussion to chat if both users involved are able to [talk in chat](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat) ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97876/disable-chat-migration-notification-if-one-of-the-users-has-insufficient-rep/318314#318314)). This is done because, even if the conversation was brought to chat, the user would not even be able to continue discussing it.

The user you were talking to in the comments only has 3 reputation, which is not enough to talk in chat, so you were not given the option of automatically moving the comments to chat.

Comment: Obviously I've been having a lot of discussion with low-rep users of late!