# Continue in Chat Option Not Shown

Tags: support, comments, chat

All comments lost and admonition that comments are not for extended discussion and the discussion should have been moved to chat -- Okay fine:

[How to reverse order numbers in a text file then write the reversed numbers back into the text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57863227/how-to-reverse-order-numbers-in-a-text-file-then-write-the-reversed-numbers-back/57863490?noredirect=1#comment102161072_57863490)

[image]

But... the option to "Continue discussions in chat" was never presented no matter how many comments were entered. How do we make the chat link appear?

Comment: Whoops -- I made a conflicting edit. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Mods get an autoflag if a comment has more than x comments. They can move the comments I think regardless of how many they are. Do note that the option is presented if the discussion is between you and an another user.

Comment: Are you using the site or the mobile app? If the site, in desktop mode or mobile mode? I only use the app (the SE app, not the dead SO one), and it never gives you the option.

Comment: The "continue discussion in chat" option only appears when there have been at least 6 back and forth (3 each) messages between two individual users, IIRC. So you can theoretically have an unlimited # of comments from all different users and never see the link appear. Edit: it also apparently requires both users have enough rep to chat in the first place.  see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381899/not-getting-would-you-like-to-automatically-move-this-discussion-to-chat-optio?rq=1 If you were chatting with OP above, they have 1 rep so cannot participate in chat, thus no link.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 60.8esr. I have noticed this on random occasions. With some questioners, I am presented with the "Continue discussion in chat" on about the 4th comment. However, on others, it just never appears. In this case there were only 2 people involved, the questioner and I. There were no less than 30 comments and still no "Continue discussion in chat" was ever triggered.